# Rails 6 routing for admin section with arguments in the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how can I organize routing for /admin section with arguments before the "/admin".

For example, /:country_id/:lang_id/admin

Path example, /ukraine/english/admin

I have tried:
scope path:"/:country_id/:lang_id/admin", :as => "admin" do
resources :cities, controller:'admin/cities'

but "admin_cities_path" create wrong internal links
<%= link_to city.title, admin_cities_path(city.id) %>

Rails returns the following UR:: /1/english/admin/cities
instead of:
/ukraine/english/admin/cities/1

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  devise_for :views

  get 'home/index', to: 'application#index'
  root to: "home#index"

  get '/:id/:lang_id/admin', to: 'admin/admin#index'
  get '/admin', to: 'admin/admin#index'



  scope path:"/:country_id/:lang_id/admin", :as => "admin" do
  #namespace :admin do
      resources :cities, controller:'admin/cities'
      resources :comments  do
          member do
            get 'approve'
            get 'disapprove'
          end
        end
      resources :countries
      resources :industries
      resources :products
      resources :languages
      resources :categories
      resources :companies
  end


  #root "articles#index"
  #get "/admin/countries", to: "countries#index"# For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  # resources :countries do
  #   resources :languages
  # end

  resources :countries

  get '/countries/', to: 'countries#index'
  get '/languages/', to: 'languages#index'
  get '/:id/', to: 'countries#show', as: 'localized_country'
  get '/:id/:lang_id/', to: 'languages#show', as: 'localized_language'
  #get '/:id/:lang_id/:category_id/', to: 'categories#show', as: 'localized_category'
  get '/:id/:lang_id/:industry_id/', to: 'industries#show', as: 'localized_industry'
  get '/:id/:lang_id/:industry_id/:category_id/', to: 'categories#show', as: 'localized_category'
  get '/:id/:lang_id/:industry_id/:category_id/:city_id/', to: 'cities#show', as: 'localized_city'

  get '/:id/:lang_id/:industry_id/:category_id/product/:product_id/', to: 'products#show', as: 'localized_product'

  resources :languages, param: :land_id
  resources :products
  resources :industries
  resources :categories, param: :category_id



  resources :products do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't get how you expect to be able to generate a URL with thee segments from a single argument. Or why you think this nesting is needed.

Comment: do you already have any code in your `route.rb` you could share?

Comment: added code of routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing what you want if its not satisfied then pls comments some code or more information to solve it.

```
   resources :country, path: '' do
    resources :language, path: '' do
      namespace "admin" do
        resource :cities
      end
    end
  end
```

The above code will reporduce the path in following format.

```
new_country_language_admin_cities   GET /:country_id/:language_id/admin/cities/new(.:format)  admin/cities#new
edit_country_language_admin_cities  GET /:country_id/:language_id/admin/cities/edit(.:format)   admin/cities#edit
```

and so on...

Comment: hi, the same problem, Rails returns the following URL: /1/english/admin/cities
instead of: 
/ukraine/english/admin/cities/1

Comment: You can use friendly_id gem: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id